# How to concatenate number to string in macro?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to concatinate a version number to a string in inno-setup preprocessor macros. I tried to use the stringer trick (used in c++ macros) like this:

```
#define stringer_helper(arg) #arg
#define stringer(arg) stringer_helper(arg)

#define version 1
#define myapp "lala " + stringer(version)
```

but get the error:

```
Illegal character in input file: '#' (0x23)
```

How is it possible to append a number define to a string define?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`Str`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=str) function to typecast your integer variable:

```
#define MyString "Text"
#define MyInteger 666
#define MyVariable MyString + Str(MyInteger)
```